# rsync vdi's to local cifs mount for backup but prevent -w option?

Tags: rsync

I'm dumping my vdi's over to a mounted cifs nas just for backup .  rsync seems to think is is local so it just copies the whole 6 gig file again rather than differences.  Can I suppress this behavior as I'm only copying at about 4 megs/sec so it takes about half an hour.

Anyone doing this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change this - there is no way your rsync process can know what portions of your file have changed before reading both versions of it. If you need the rdiff functionality, you *have* to run an rsync receiver at the CIFS NAS' side.